# dayclick not showing modal popup

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

dayClick is not showing the modal popup when click on a day so can't create a task/appointment, below is the section of coding I have related to dayClick. Below is the HTML as well for the modal popup for the dayClick function showing the id of the modal popup and is the correct id of the modal popup within the dayClick function. I have included the jquery and bootstrap.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid' ],
defaultDate: new Date(),
editable: true,
timezone: 'Europe/London',
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
displayEventTime: false,
locale: "en-gb",
firstDay: 1,

events: "fetch-tasks-appointments.php",

    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    $("#success-modal").modal("show");
    $('#title').text(date.format);            
    $("#startdate").val(date.format());
    $('#starttime').text(date.format);
    $("#enddate").val(date.format());
    $('#endtime').text(date.format);
    },

    });

    calendar.render();
    });
    </script>
  <div class="modal fade" id="success-modal" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header success-modal">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
  label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
<form action="tasks-appointments-calendar.php" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="eventtitle">Event Title:</label>
  <input type="title" name="title" class="form-control" id="title">
  <input type="date" name="startdate" class="form-control" id="startdate">
  <input type="text" name="starttime" class="form-control" id="starttime">
  <input type="date" name="enddate" class="form-control" id="enddate">
  <input type="text" name="endtime" class="form-control" id="endtime">
</div>
<button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success float-button-light">Save Task/Appointment</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in your console? Did you include jQuery in your page? Did you include bootstrap? Did you definitely select the right element? You didn't provide any of that information, but those are important clues. Please provide the relevant HTML, and also include useful debugging information. We are not psychic, and we cannot see your screen. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console and have got jquery in the page and included bootstrap

I have checked the id in the dayClick function and is the correct one for the modal popup.

I did try and add the HTML coding to the original post but said I had to add more text as there was more code than text

I'll try again and add the HTML

Comment: Oh hang on, I just realised...you're using fullCalendar 4. There's no such thing as "dayClick" any more...check the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc . It's called "dateClick" instead: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick .

Comment: If you correct that, and a couple of other issues, then your code works fine: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GbqVGR

Comment: Ahhh ok sorry didn't realise, I'll look at the docs and the new function that replaced dayClick and hopefully will get it working

Comment: But you know, if you're using this to allow users to create events, you're supposed to use [select](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) instead of date/dayClick - it a) provides more flexibility to the user, so they can select multiple days, or (within an "agenda" view) select specific times of day, and b) provides you useful info like separate start and end dates/times in the callback. The user can drag their mouse to select a specific area of time, rather than just clicking in one place. This is the way fullCalendar recommends you to implement selection of dates.

Comment: Thank you so much ADyson, it's working all ok now, one last thing if possible. can a timepicker be added for the starttime and endtime on the modal popup for new tasks/appointments? I'll look on Google to see how to go about doing it and see if can figure it out

Comment: It's just myself using the calendar and don;t think I'll be adding tasks/appointments that will be multiple days as will mostly be single day tasks/appointments

Comment: "can a timepicker be added for the starttime and endtime on the modal popup"...I don't see why not, if you can find one you like. Your form is no different to any other. It's not a fullCalendar related issue, for sure.